# Create Image and PlaceHolder from code behind - dynamic

Tags: asp.net, image, dynamic, placeholder

I want read images from my database but they have to be inside of unorderd list.
I have an Handler do get the source of imgUrl

```
s+= "< ul>";
while (reader.Read())
{
    id = reader.GetInt32(0);
    s += "< li>< div>";
    s += "< a href='#'>< img src='~/Handlers/ShowImage.ashx?id=" + id + "'/>< /a>";
    s += "</ div></ li>";
}
s+="< /ul>";
```

after that I use a Literal who is declared in aspx to pass this block of html code.

```
myLiteral.text = s;
```

The problem is: my handler never is executed, so i never get the img source.
To solve that I start to use an PlaceHolder instead write the tag "< img ... />".

So i have:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    id = reader.GetInt32(0);

    PlaceHolder holder = new PlaceHolder();
    Image img = new Image();
    img.ImageUrl = "~/Handlers/ShowImage.ashx?id=" + id;
    holder.Controls.Add(img);

    s += " li div";
    s += " a href='" + reader.GetString(1) + "'" + holder + " /a";
    s += " /div /li";
}
```

this way the handler executes but my holder just pass the `.toString()` :S

Someone help-me? And, is this the best way for what I want?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try....

```
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
  holder.RenderControl(htw);
  string s = sw.ToString();
```

"s" is what you want.

Comment: thanks, it works!! I never tried HtmlTextWriter neither renderCrontrol!

Comment: @user1546424, Let me know what you what to know more about it? if it works, then accept this answer.

Comment: is this the best way to do that? And should I use an Handler to read images?

Comment: If you have images in the database or in remote server, then Handler is good way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify your question a bit?

- When you say you have a handler... is that an HttpHandler?
- Where is your code running? Is it on the codebehind of your page? What method is it?

Also, if you want to render the HTML strings yourself, it's recommended that you use the StringBuilder class instead of just "s+="

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, my ShowImage is an IHttpHandler.
The code is running in codebehind of my aspx file

Comment: I think Amit Prajapati gave a very good answer to this already :)